# Print data of Nodes with multiple children [Java]

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, tree

Hey to all Stackoverflowers!:D

**This is my first question ever on stackoverflow, I appreciate any advice for my next questions!**

I want to print out the data of all nodes in a tree data structure. I already have some code, but I get weird results.

-Every node can have multiple children, those are stored in a List of nodes

-I always start with the root

Here is my Code:

```
    public static void printTree(Knoten blatt){      
    Aufgabe1.Gewichte = Aufgabe1.Gewichte + blatt.Gewicht;
    System.out.println(blatt.Gewicht);

    for(int i=0;i<blatt.children.size();i++) {
        blatt = blatt.children.get(i);
        printTree(blatt);
    } 
}
```

But if I call this function my programm does not print out all nodes.
I know this since I print the data while creating the nodes, I get this:

```
3.0
27.0
-6.0
-7.0
10.0
-5.0
-47.0
-13.0
-5.0
```

If I print it out with my recursive function, I get this:

```
3.0
27.0
-6.0
-7.0
10.0
-5.0
-47.0
-13.0
```

-47 is the parent, with the children -13 and -5, -5 just doesnt want to get printed tho.

If I print it out manually, like root.children.children...get(i) whatever, I can access both kids, with the right data... 
I seriously have no clue where my fault is in my code, would be great if someone can help me...
I am sure im just kinda blind :D

I also tried some other trees, sometimes this error wont show up, sometimes it will...

The Tree-Structure looks like this:
[image]

Thanks for your help, I hope my question is understandable

Comment: oh, yes, I made a mistake with the formatting, thanks!

Comment: Can you also post the tree structure you tested?  I suspect that you may be confused by the output due to the order in which everything is being printed.

Comment: Do you mean the data of the tree, or my tree data structure?:D

Comment: I am trying to correlate the linear output you showed us with the actual structure of the tree.  Otherwise, how can anyone know if there is even a real problem?

Comment: here you go, I hope this helps you

Comment: You code is not structure correctly. This is a bad line of code: blatt = blatt.children.get(i);

Comment: You should do something like Print node - > now Print all the node's children -> if(node has no children){print next nodes children}. What you are doing is printing the nodes first child.

Comment: I have the feeling that your input tree might be missing data.  `7`'s children of `-47` and `10` are both being printed, and I see no reason why both of `-47` 's children would not also be printed.

Comment: Thanks for everyone trying to help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the current node variable (= blatt) while you are iterating the children by re-assigning `blatt` in the loop. This means that you continue at the child's second child (instead of the second direct child) after the first child was printed. Fix:

```
public static void printTree(Knoten blatt) {      
  Aufgabe1.Gewichte = Aufgabe1.Gewichte + blatt.Gewicht;
  System.out.println(blatt.Gewicht);

  for(int i = 0; i < blatt.children.size(); i++) {
    Knoten kind = blatt.children.get(i);  // Don't overwrite blatt here
    printTree(kind);
  } 
}
```

Comment: `blatt` is just a reference, so would reassigning it to something else change the underlying data to which it points?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, and I did not intend to claim so (edited the text to be less ambiguous)